Getting the name of the variable assigned to a new variable in R
Suppose I do the following
y <- c(1,2,3)   
x <- y

Now I want to know what variable was used in the assignment of x.  I want it to return "y".  Any idea how to do that?

Why do you have this requirement?

This sounds like a classic XY problem (excuse the pun). Can you explain in what context you need to do this and why? There is likely a better approach to whatever problem you're trying to solve.

1) This will show which variables in the environment envir are identical to the passed argument.
A few caveats:

This is not a guarantee since it would be possible to have multiple variables that are identical but it is likely to provide the answer in most cases.

It can't really know which came first so if we pass it y it will return "x".


Code--
y <- c(1,2,3)
x <- y

get_original <- function(x, envir = parent.frame()) {
  name <- deparse1(substitute(x))
  setdiff(names(Filter(isTRUE, eapply(envir, identical, x))), name)
}

get_original(x)
## [1] "y"

get_original(y)
## [1] "x"

2) This is a different approach.  It loads the history of the session, finds the last time the passed argument was assigned to in the history and then shows the right hand side of the assignment.  The limitation here is that the assignment must still be in the history.
get_original2 <- function(x) {
  name <- deparse1(substitute(x))
  temp <- tempfile()
  savehistory(temp)
  hist <- readLines(temp)
  unlink(temp)
  pat <- sprintf("^\\s*%s\\s*<-", name)
  grep(pat, hist, value = TRUE) |> tail(1) |> sub(".*<-", "", x = _) |> trimws()
}

get_original2(x)
## [1] y

3) If we knew ahead of time that we wanted to find the origin of a variable we could write a custom assignment function.
assign.orig <- function(x, value, envir = parent.frame()) {
  name <- deparse1(substitute(x))
  assign(name, value, envir = envir)
  attr(envir[[name]], "orig") <- deparse1(substitute(value))
  invisible()
}

assign.orig(x, y)  # create x from y
attr(x, "orig") # discover where x came from
## [1] "y"


I stand by my comment that this is a bad idea and there's basically no reason you should ever do it. However, it piqued my interest. Here is an alternative approach - a function which walks all available environments and will tell you if there exists another object that shares the same memory address.
find_same_obj <- function(
    x, n_envs = 1, obj_name = NULL,
    env = pos.to.env(n_envs), env_name = NULL,
    find_all = FALSE) {
    if (identical(env, emptyenv())) {
        if(!find_all) message("Object not found")
        return(invisible(NULL))
    }
    args <- as.list(match.call())

    # Get the name of the object
    if (is.null(obj_name)) {
        if (length(args$x) == 1) {
            obj_name <- toString(args$x)
        } else {
            # in case we pass something like `base::plot`
            obj_name <- toString(args$x[[length(args$x)]])
        }
    }
    for (obj_str in ls(env)) {
        obj <- get(obj_str, envir = env)

        # Search any environments not on the search path
        if (is.environment(obj)) {
            if (find_same_obj(
                x, n_envs, obj_name,
                env = obj, env_name = obj_str
            )) {
                return(invisible(TRUE))
            }
        }
        if (obj_str == obj_name) next() # don't match itself
        if (lobstr::obj_addr(x) == lobstr::obj_addr(obj)) {
            message("Object found: `", obj_str, "` ", appendLF = FALSE)
            print(env_name %||% base::pos.to.env(n_envs))
            if(!find_all) return(invisible(TRUE))
        }
    }

    # If not walking down envs not on search path
    # then recurisvely walk up search path
    if (is.null(env_name)) {
        find_same_obj(x, n_envs + 1, obj_name, find_all = find_all)
    }
    invisible(FALSE)
}

Here it is in action:
y <- c(1,2,3)
x <- y
find_same_obj(x) 
# Object found: `y` <environment: R_GlobalEnv> 

Of course if you change the original object they will no longer share a memory address:
y <- "a"
find_same_obj(x)
# Object not found

However, it will not give false positives if two objects are identical but do not share a memory address:
a <- 3; b <- 3; c <- b
find_same_obj(c) 
# Object found: `b` <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
find_same_obj(a) 
# Object not found

It does not need the objects to exist in the global environment:
aov2 <- stats::aov
find_same_obj(aov2) 
# Object found: `aov` <environment: package:stats>

Or even in environments on the function's search() path:
env1 <- new.env()
env1$a <- 1
env1$b <- env1$a
find_same_obj(env1$a)
# Object found: `b` [1] "env1"

Or in environments which are on the same search path:
env2 <- new.env()
env2$c <- env1$a
find_same_obj(env2$c)
# Object found: `a` [1] "env1"

And the objects need not have been defined using the assignment operator <-:
assign("plot2", base::plot, envir = env2)
find_same_obj(env2$plot2)
# Object found: `plot` <environment: package:graphics>

Also it does not need to have been defined in your code. For example, the magrittr::extract() function is defined as extract <- `[`. So we can do:
find_same_obj(magrittr::extract)
# Object found: `[` <environment: base>

By default this will stop at the first object it has found but if you want it to return multiple objects then set find_all = TRUE:
i <- 2; j = i; assign("k", i); k->l
find_same_obj(i, find_all = TRUE)
# Object found: `j` <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
# Object found: `k` <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
# Object found: `l` <environment: R_GlobalEnv>

I still can't think why you would do this, though.
